# Promote one-bit wire to 64-bit bus

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have a 64-bit bus, and I would like to `&` every bit of the bus with a one-bit wire. What's the best way to do this? I would like to do something like below, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
logic [63:0] bus, other_bus;
logic signal;
...
bus = other_bus & signal;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replicate `signal` 64 times.  Refer to the IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 11.4.12.1 "Replication operator":

```
bus = other_bus & {64{signal}};
```

Answer (score -2):

you can also try this :- 

`for (i=0,i<=63;i++) begin:ANDLoop
    bus[i] = other_bus[i] & signal;
end:ANDLoop`